# Event sent to UrlFetchApp using appsscript does not appear in Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-sheets, google-analytics, urlfetch

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=1060320920.1612316285&t=event&ec=transaction&ea=call&el=202102081703_0507-1474-0311&ni=TRUE&ti=offline&ta=&tr=100&tt=0&ts=0&pa =callOrder&pr1id=&pr1nm=product_name&pr1qt=1&pr1pr=100&pr1ca=machine
```

I am trying to send the above URL to Google Analytics using apps scipt.

When I enter it directly into the URL address bar, an event is sent.
However, if you refer to the existing data (POST method) and send it to apps scipt, the event is not caught in Analytics.

Comment: Hi ! Please share a sample code *with no sensitive data* of how you are making this POST request from Apps Script so that we can see if the code has any issue. Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see if you have Exclude spam and bot option checked in View settings. That could be the cause.

Comment: Adding a value to the parameter 'ua' solved it! Thank you for answer.

Comment: Yes, because with the browser User Agent you managed not to be recognized as a bot.